# std::make_tuple with the input of a manipulated std::tuple unsing concepts in c++20

Tags: c++, tuples, c++20, c++-concepts

Kindly considere the following [godbolted code](https://godbolt.org/z/hW9brM) written for c++20:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>

template <typename T, std::size_t ...I, typename F>
void tuple_foreach_impl(T&& tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>, F&& func)
{
    using dummy_array = int[];
    dummy_array{(void(func(std::get<I>(tuple))), 0)..., 0};
}

template <typename T, typename F>
void tuple_foreach(T&& tuple, F&& func)
{
    constexpr int size = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value;
    tuple_foreach_impl(std::forward<T>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<size>{},
        std::forward<F>(func));
}

template<typename T>
concept IsOfTypeInt = std::same_as<T, int>;

template<typename T>
concept IsNotOfTypeInt = not IsOfTypeInt<T>;

template<IsOfTypeInt T>
int* ToPtrIfInt(T& arg) { return &arg;}

template<IsNotOfTypeInt T>
T& ToPtrIfInt(T& arg) { return arg;}

template <typename... T, std::size_t... I>
auto ConvertTupleImp(const std::tuple<T...>& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(ToPtrIfInt(std::get<I>(t))...);
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::make_tuple(1.1,3.14159,42);
    auto t2 = ConvertTupleImp(t1, std::make_index_sequence<3>());

    tuple_foreach(t2, [](auto&& value)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    });
}
```

The output reads:

```
Program returned: 0
1.1
3.14159
42
```

The purpose of the function `ToPtrIfInt` is to return a pointer to the input `int` if the input is of type `int`. In any other case `ToPtrIfInt` should return the input object. As you can see in the output the last element (value 42) is not converted to its pointer. So the code does not work. My guess ist hat I have to use `ToPtrIfInt(std::forward<…>(std::get<I>(t)))...` But I am not able to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `tuple_foreach_impl`... We have `std::apply`, and fold expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constness issue: your tuple is const, so you pass `const int&` and `const int` is not a `int`. removing const solve your issue:

```
template <typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
auto ConvertTupleImp(std::tuple<Ts...>& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(ToPtrIfInt(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5YMs5P)

Alternatively, you might change your concept to handle const (and reference)

```
template<typename T>
concept IsOfTypeInt = std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>, int>;
```

You have to fix implementation of `ToPtrIfInt` to have correct return too.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4e8eYK)